# Cross-domain POST Ajax request without using proxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Is it even possible to perform a cross-domain POST Ajax request without using proxy? I'm willing to use any kind of library to do this.

P.S. Request response is in JSON format.

Comment: Is the cross-domain under your control/do they allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing?

Comment: No, it's not. I'm trying to perform a 'POST statuses/update' operation with Twitter API. I guess they allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

Comment: If twitter sends header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, then you don't need proxy. Browsers will look for this header and allow cross domain post ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it if you don't control the server.  Server side proxy is your only option.

Good thing is server-side proxy is fairly easy to do.  Just create an endpoint that accepts the details of the request you want to make (http method, url, params), and then use whatever URL mechanism your framework of choice has to hit the other domain.

Answer (score -1):

The other possibility is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP%20JSONP), which uses a script tag instead of AJAX

However, that requires that the server already support it, since it needs to wrap the returned JSON

Comment: @Sergey: Duh, didn't read the question fully! But why does the OP need POST only?